# jinja2 collecting and counting same strings

Tags: python, mongodb, jinja2, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I want to collect same tags at the frontend or my view page coming from the database. Tags are collecting in list.

**model.py**

```
class Note(Document):
    tags = db.ListField(db.StringField())
```

Example of MongoDB data:

```
"notes" : [ 
        {
            "title":"lipsum",
            "content":"lipsum",
            "tags" : [ 
                "python", 
                "OOP", 
                "mongoengine"
            ]
        }, 

        {
            "title":"lipsum2",
            "content":"lipsum2",
            "tags" : [ 
                "sql", 
                "functional", 
                "mongoengine",
                "python"
            ]
        }
```

How can I get the following result from jinja2, python, flask.ext or mongoengine itself?

```
mongoengine 2
OOP
functional
python 2
sql
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I produce a dictionary of tag names and counts in Python and then pass that as a parameter to your template (rather than trying to perform this computation with jinja2 in the template itself).

Comment: thanks @larsks I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The mongoengine [`QuerySet.distinct`](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/apireference.html?highlight=distinct#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.distinct) and [`QuerySet.count`](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/apireference.html?highlight=distinct#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.count) functions can be your friend here:

```
tag_counts = {}
tag_names = Note.objects.distinct('tags')
for tag in tag_names:
    tag_counts [tag] = Note.objects(tags=tag).count()
```

or in one line:

```
dict([(tag, Note.objects(tags=tag).count()) for tag in Note.objects.distinct('tags')])
```

These both construct this dictionary:

```
{'OOP':1, 'mongoengine':2 ,'python': 2, 'functional':1, 'sql':1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't define anything like as a**tag** _(tags=tag)_.  The **tags** variable is coming from the model but I did not understand **tag** where is come from?

Comment: `tag` is coming from the the python list comprehension. I will edit the answer to make it more clear.